# Materialize select how to set constrain width to false

Tags: material-design, materialize

How do we make materialize select dropdown options to be not constrained in their width? Right now they have same width as the control and words wrapped.
http://www.codeply.com/go/unDArvEuR0
Html:

```
<div class="input-field col s1">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1 longgggg tesxtas dsada</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2 asd  very longggg</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Js:

   `$('select').material_select();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `col s1` classes from your select or play around with them.

Comment: I want the base drop down to use only s1 of space, which is why I have that.

Answer (score 4):

This will make items not wrap and the container expand to fit the items:

```
ul.select-dropdown,
ul.dropdown-content {
  width: auto !important;

  li > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely perfect answer, but better. add below css class to your project.

```
ul.select-dropdown,ul.dropdown-content{
    width:200% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable width constraint, you can do it with the following JS code (just add it after material_select call)

```
$('select').siblings('input').attr("data-constrainwidth", false);
```

The setting itself is from http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html, but for some reason, there is only a documentation for a *button*. However with this JS call, you can achieve the same functionality on *select*

Answer (score 0):

Setting `min-width` on the select dropdown can be a quick temporary fix as well. Dropdowns are coded to not give `inline style width` less than `min-width` .